# How to know when a user has cancelled page unloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onbeforeunload

My website shows the custom modal window with loader animation when a user tries to navigate to another page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    w.modalForms.loading.show(true); // true stands for permanent
};
```

It works great except for the following scenario: for example, the user has clicked a wrong link and pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or clicked browser "Stop" button) to cancel navigating away. As the result, the loading modal will not disappear, and he will have to update the page to be able to work with the website.

I want to know when a user cancels unloading \ navigating away.
Just something like:

```
window.onunloadcancelled = function() {
    w.modalForms.loading.hide();
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try a time out, once the request to the new webpage is fired. There is no cross browser solution that detects when the user hits a stop button.

For the esc key, you can capture the event and remove the

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 27) {
     w.modalForms.loading.hide();
}
```

});

You can start watching for the ESC key after showing the modal. And then remove the listener for keyup